# Is there any geospatial support available for OrientDb?

Tags: database, geospatial, orientdb, spatial-index

Is there any geospatial support available for OrientDB (wether its included or from 3rd party vendors)?

In particular I need the ability to build **spatial-indexes** on my geo-data.

Comment: At the downvoter: What was the downvote for? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Since SBTree supports range queries, as I understand it, you could efficiently use the *distance()* function.

Sources:

- https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Where#wiki-functions
- https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes
- https://code.google.com/p/orient/source/browse/trunk/tests/src/test/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/test/database/auto/GEOTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Is Lucene Spatial index you are looking for? See the documentation:

- https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-lucene/wiki/Spatial-Index